# как работать с транзакциями из фронтенда

Tags: php, laravel

Фронтенд на vue, бекенд на ларавеле. В беке сделал контроллер транзакций

```
 class TransactionsController
{

    public function beginTransaction()
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
    }

    public function rollBack()
    {
        DB::rollBack();
    }

    public function commit()
    {
        DB::commit();
    }
}
```

Из фронта через axios вызываю метод beginTransaction, затем создаю несколько записей в разных таблицах с помощью соответствующих контроллеров. Вызываю rollBack. Отката не происходит. Насколько я понимаю это потому, что вызывается в разных сессиях. А хотелось бы. Подскажите как поступать в таких случаях.

Comment: Плохая идея давать прямой доступ к БД из фронта даже для транзакционного контроля.. Лучше будет сделать атомарные функции, инкапсулирующие логику работы с БД. По вашему вопросу - если при завершении работы PHP кода commit/rollback не вызывается, то транзакция отменяется. У вас запрос на функцию контролёра - отдельный запуск всего приложения, и в итоге вызывая beginTransaction не вызывается commit/rollback в том же запуске приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Никак.
В разных сессиях никаких транзакций не может быть по определению.

Транзакция может быть реализована только в рамках одного и того же соединения с БД. То есть в рамках только одного запроса к бэкенду.

Как вариант можно копить данные в сессии и на самом последнем этапе выполнить в рамках транзакции.

Но сдается мне, что ты просто не понимаешь, что это такое и транзакция на самом деле здесь не нужна.

Comment: А нельзя ли за один раз передать несколько запросов в массиве и чтобы back их как нибудь отработал?

Comment: за один раз можно

Comment: А может быть какую нибудь ссылочку как копить данные в сессии в ларавеле.

Comment: в адресной строке своего браузера пишешь ларавель сессии. и видишь примерно пол-миллиона ссылок.